# is it possible to get the user in api without using passport using laravel default auth

Tags: php, laravel

I have an application which is monolithic. Now I want to get the authenticated `user` in just like 2 `apis` in my application. I know that I can use laravel `passport` to generate tokens and get the `user` but I want to know if it's possible to get the authenticated `user` on website in api too.
Now in my `api` controller when I `dd()` below options I get null:

```
    dd(auth()->user());
    dd(auth('api')->user());
    dd(Auth::user());
```

I am using laravel `fortify` for user login.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. So I created middleware to if Bearer token existed you can get the user with Auth::user and if there isn't Bearer Token, Application still works without auth. The below middleware worked with Auth & Unauth.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Models\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Configuration;

class CheckUserAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next){

        $value = $request->bearerToken(); // Get auth token

        if(!$value) { // Stop auth if token not sent
            return $next($request);
        }

        $parser = Configuration::forUnsecuredSigner()->parser();//new \Lcobucci\JWT\Token\Parser();
        $token = $parser->parse($value); // Parse token

        if($token->isExpired(Carbon::now())) { // Check token is expired
            return $next($request);
        }

        if(@ !$id = $token->claims()->all()['jti']) {// Get user ID
            return $next($request);
        }

        $data = DB::table('oauth_access_tokens') // Check id is valid
        ->select('user_id')
            ->where('id', $id)
            ->first();

        if($data) { // If oauth_access_tokens record is exists
            $user = User::find($data->user_id); // Load user object model
            if($user) { // check if user found
                if($user->active) { // Check user is available
                    Auth::setUser($user); // Set user in Auth object for getting in controllers
                }
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```